# What do these 'smbclient' samba information mean?

Tags: linux, windows, samba

On a gentoo Linux I am making a call to `smbclient`, which among others show the following output (when connecting to a Windows share on some Windows computer):

```
Domain=[LN_DOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.24]
```

What do these information tell me? Especially, what is the number '3.6.24' in the last part? It looks like a version number, but `/usr/bin/smbclient -V` returns:

```
Version 3.0.33
```

So what does the number `3.6.24` mean? There does not seem to be anything on the man pages.

Full example to reproduce this outcome (run on the Linux client, to list the content of a directory on a Windows share on a Windoes7/Windoes XP machine):

```
/usr/bin/smbclient "//123.123.123.123/Backup" "password" -U "username"  -W "workspace" -D "Directory" -c "ls"
```

Comment: Obviously, the version of the server (smbd/nmbd) is not required to match the version of the client (smbclient).

Comment: This was not my question - but then the number '3.6.24' is the version of samba running on windows? Is that correct?

Comment: The server is probably a Linux machine running Samba 3.6.24. If it were a Windows machine, you would see "Windows" in "OS" and "Server".

Comment: @Alex: Windows doesn't run Samba … Samba is the Linux/Unix implementation of Windows' SMB protocol. Btw, what does `uname -r` return on your Linux box? Maybe 3.6.24 is the kernel version.